# Gmail notifier for multiple accounts (business and personal)

Tags: gmail

I have several user accounts with Google Apps Gmail and one user account with free Gmail.

I need a way to get notification for incoming emails. How could I do that? Which notifiers are availble?

Comment: … assuming Windows?

Comment: @slhck:ｙｅｓ　ｗｉｎｄｏｗｓ　７

Comment: May I ask what's up with your writing?

Answer (score 0):

Spiffy allows up to 5 different accounts... http://members.multiweb.nl/kevin/spiffy/

Comment: ＠ｐｅｒｌ．ｊ：　ｙｅｓ　ｂｕｔ　ｉｔ　ｄｏｅｓｎ＇ｔ　ｓｕｐｐｏｒｔ　ｍｕｌｔｉｐｌｅ　ａｃｃｏｕｎｔｓ

Answer (score 0):

Check this [GmailAssistant](http://gmailassistant.sourceforge.net/) ..
As per its

Notifier for multiple Gmail accounts. Free software written in Java.
Latest version: 2.0 (2008-09-07)

GmailAssistant is a notifier for multiple Gmail and Google Apps email accounts. It accesses your accounts securely using IMAP over SSL. Choose from various notification options (unread mails in Inbox only, All Mails, or with specified labels) and alert methods (popup message, chime, blink keyboard LED). Free and open source software written in Java.
[image]
[image]